# how to implement 1+1=3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am feeling that following solution

```
class Fixnum
  def +(x)
    self + x + 1
  end
end
```

should not work, since `+` will be called recursively.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I laughed after reading the question.

Comment: You've defined an instance method on `Object`: `self.class.instance_method(:+).owner #=> Object`, so you need to invoke it like this (for example): `Object.new + 3`. That's probably not what you want and it's obviously not going to work. If you write `1+2`, you are using `Fixnum#+`, because `1.class #=> Fixnum`.

Comment: Whatever the reason, don't go down this path, man! There's still time to turn back.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed Maybe his subconscious wants to have a baby?

Comment: @FredOverflow well that's a way a true programmer would go about it ;)

Comment: The important part to take away from this question is that we can write methods using symbols, they aren't reserved for Ruby: https://gist.github.com/8f4837a817f9be36f812

Comment: See also http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate, but I think I'm beginning to understand why--as here-- it's so common for non-Rubiest to mark a Ruby question a duplicate. None of  the five duplicate-markers above seem to have answered any Ruby questions. However, one, in his profile, boasts, "Top 5 Close Voters of All Time". I had no idea there was competition for closing questions at SO.

Answer (score 28):

Using `alias` to store the original `+` like this works:

```
class Fixnum
  alias old_plus +
  def +(x)
    old_plus(x).succ
  end
end
```

Comment: using 
    old_plus(x).old_plus(1)
works too.

Comment: I don't think it is right to break all the `+` functionality, only `1 + 1 = 3` should be affected. So I suggest the new `+(x)` should be `(x == 1 && self == 1) ? 3 : old_plus(x)`

Comment: @xlembouras I'm sure it's only for fun, no one would use it in practice :)

Comment: @YuHao at my coworker's prior workplace, someone overloaded assignment operator `=` and made it do some business logic. Then he did another hack: he added `a=a;` whose purpose was to trigger this logic. Shortly after, someone removed that obviously meaningless `a=a;` statement... boom. Magnitude of tests suddenly failed. Needless to say, it took very long time to discover the reason.

Comment: @rr-: At least you had tests.

Answer (score 26):

Another way is to [`prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-prepend) a module:

```
module PlusOne
  def +(x)
    super.succ
  end
end

Fixnum.prepend(PlusOne)

1 + 1 #=> 3
```

Comment: you are a genius. You always have a different solution! :)

Comment: Ever since prepend became a thing, I've always prefered it over overriding methods directly. Not only is it easier to do it this way, but it's also clearer and results in an inheritance chain which documents your modifications quite nicely. (E.g. `Fixnum.ancestors.first #=> PlusOne`)

Comment: One minor issue though: `prepend` is private. So either do `Fixnum.send(:prepend, PlusOne)`, or `class Fixnum; prepend PlusOne; end`

Comment: @Ajedi32 `Module#include` and `Module#prepend` are public in Ruby 2.1 and later.